# Pulling Information into new workbook from dynamic Worksheet Name

Tags: excel, vba

VBA issue coming up.

I have a revenue tracker ("revenue tracker.xlsx") file in which I have created a macro that filters a particular month entries and creates a new worksheets based on the months entries (worksheets are entitled "January", "February" etc)

I would now like to pull this newly generated worksheet over to a new workbook ("Cost Loader.xlsx"), considering the worksheet name is dynamic.

my code is as follows

```
Sub PullRevenueTrackerInfo()

'Pull info from respective column into correct column on to Cost Loader

Dim ws_mth As Workbook, ws_charges As Workbook, mapFromColumn As Variant, mapToColumn As Variant
    Dim lastCell As Integer, i As Integer, nextCell As Integer, arrCopy As Variant

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim wsNames As Variant, ws As Worksheet, w As Worksheet, El As Variant, boolFound As Boolean


'2. Dynamic worksheets

wsNames = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December", ",")
    For Each w In Worksheets
        For Each El In wsNames
    If w.Name = El Then
        Set ws = w: boolFound = True: Exit For
    End If
    Next El
    Next w


'3. pull information

     Set ws_mth = Workbooks("Revenue Tracker.xlsx")
    Set ws_charges = Workbooks("Cost Loader.xlsx")
    
    mapFromColumn = Array("I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P")  after
    mapToColumn = Array("A", "B", "C", "G", "K", "M", "H", "J") 

  For i = 0 To UBound(mapFromColumn)
  With ws_mth.Worksheets(ws.Name)   'run time 91 error - object variable not set
            lastCell = ws_mth.Sheets(ws.Name).ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.Rows.Count
            arrCopy = .Range(mapFromColumn(i) & 2 & ":" & mapFromColumn(i) & lastCell)
        End With

            With ws_charges.Worksheets(1)
                nextCell = .Range(mapToColumn(i) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range(mapToColumn(i) & nextCell).Resize(UBound(arrCopy), UBound(arrCopy, 2)).Value = arrCopy
            End With
            Next i
```

I am getting a type mismatch error arising when trying to map from particular columns in which I have data. Ive tried a couple of different things, its pretty frustrating at the moment, I cant seem to get it to work. thanks in advance!

EDIT: run time error appears `With ws_mth.Worksheets(ws.Name), im not sure how to call the correct worksheet

Comment: `Worksheets(w)` expects an integer or string in the brackets i.e. the sheet index number or string name. So, use `Worksheets(w.Name)`

Comment: having amended to your recommendation , unfortuantely i am now getting the error "object variable not set"

Comment: Sorry, read it too quickly. It's `ws` you want to use for the found worksheet? Then it should be `Worksheets(ws.Name)`

Comment: yes, still not much love from that attempt i'm afraid, trying a couple of new things, will report back if I can get to work

Comment: Have you tested the `ws` variable? Do you know if the preceding loop has actually found a match? The Exit For will just exit the inner loop: is that what you want? You are setting boolFound (though it hasn’t been initialised to False): did you plan to use that somewhere?

Comment: Also what file is this in? In the search loop you are just using an unqualified `Worksheets` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reformated your code a bit, edited it, commented and I think your problem is solved:

```
Sub PullRevenueTrackerInfo()

'Pull info from respective column into correct column on to Cost Loader
    
    'Try to "group" variables like so, it helps you and others to catch-up while debugging
    Dim wb_mth, wb_charges As Workbook
    Dim mapFromColumn, mapToColumn As Variant
    Dim lastCell, i, nextCell As Integer
    Dim arrCopy, wsNames As Variant

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim ws, w As Worksheet
    Dim El As Variant
    Dim boolFound As Boolean

    'Pay attention to variable naming!
    'You named those as "ws_mth" and "ws_charges"
    'which indicates you want Worksheets, but you want Workbooks
    Set wb_mth = Workbooks("Revenue Tracker.xlsx")
    Set wb_charges = Workbooks("Cost Loader.xlsx")

'2. Dynamic worksheets

wsNames = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December", ",")
    
    For Each w In wb_mth.Worksheets
        For Each El In wsNames
            If w.Name = El Then
                'Again, pay attention. You shall specify in which workbook your "ws" is
                Set ws = w: boolFound = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next El
        If boolFound Then Exit For 'Add this to exit second loop
    Next w


'3. pull information
    
    mapFromColumn = Array("I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P")
    mapToColumn = Array("A", "B", "C", "G", "K", "M", "H", "J")

    For i = 0 To UBound(mapFromColumn)
        'Main problem. You tried to reference to worksheet by name,
        'while your target worksheet, as an object is already set (ws), so you can do:
        
        'With ws_mth.Worksheets(ws.Name)   'run time 91 error - object variable not set
        With ws
            lastCell = .ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.Rows.Count
            arrCopy = .Range(mapFromColumn(i) & 2 & ":" & mapFromColumn(i) & lastCell)
        End With

        With wb_charges.Worksheets(1)
            nextCell = .Range(mapToColumn(i) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range(mapToColumn(i) & nextCell).Resize(UBound(arrCopy), UBound(arrCopy, 2)).Value = arrCopy
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

I assume that you expect such output (here I ran macro twice):[image]

Please let me know, if it works for you :)

Comment: thank you so much, and apologies for the latish reply! ive been away on holiday during the interval. really appreciate it